# How do I set a default selected option in a Web UI <select> tag?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have have a `<select>` tag with a few options. How do I set the initially default selected option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the Dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

List<String> fruits = const <String>['apples', 'bananas', 'pears'];

@observable
String selected = 'pears';

void main() { }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```dart
<p>Hello world from Dart!  You chose {{ selected }}</p>

<select name="fruit" template iterate="fruit in fruits" bind-value="selected">
  <option selected="{{selected == fruit}}">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

Note, there is an [open request](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/472) to make this a bit easier. In the meantime, the above code should work for you.